# Expected stack map table for method with non-linear control flow

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

When I targeting to Android 30+, I got a bunch of warnings in the title about the library provided by Samsung (accessory-v2.6.4.jar) to included in the project for communicating with a Galaxy wearable.

1. Can I get rid of this warning?
2. Can I ignore this warning?
3. What is this warning meaning?